# A calculation with Bessel functions

Tags: bessel-functions

I'm reading "Introduction to Quantum Effects in Gravity - Mukhanov, Winitzki" and despite treating purely physical subjects, I'm stuck with a mathematical calculation that I suspect involve some properties of Bessel or Gamma functions that I don't know. I have this expression
$$ f \doteq \sqrt{a|x|} ( A J_\alpha (a|x|) + B Y_\alpha (a|x|) ) $$
where $a$ and $\alpha$ are some real positive values, and a constraint
$$ \frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x} f^\ast - f \frac{\text{d}f^\ast}{\text{d}x}=2\mathrm{i} $$
In the book (7.3.3 pag. 96) is stated that this brings to
$$ A B^\ast - A^\ast B = \frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}{a} $$
but I totally don't see how. I tried doing an explicit calculation, but I'm stuck in trying to demonstrate that
$$
\frac{\text{sgn}\,x}{|x|} \sum_{n,m=0}^{+\infty}
\frac{ (-1)^{n+m} (\alpha+n-m) }{ n!m! \Gamma(n+\alpha+1) \Gamma(m-\alpha+1) } \left( \frac{a|x|}{2} \right)^{2(n+m)}
=
-\pi\sin{\pi\alpha}
$$
Also the explicit way doesn't seem very pleasant to me, but trying to start from differential Bessel equation and manipulating a bit doesn't get me to any result. What is the way to do it?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#properties

Comment: @user619894 I saw Bessel function and equation pages on wikipedia, and now I watched the page you suggested, but I can't find a solution sorry

Comment: I meant this:  $A_\alpha(x) \frac{dB_\alpha}{dx} - \frac{dA_\alpha}{dx} B_\alpha(x) = \frac{C_\alpha}{x}$

Comment: @user619894 Nice!! I didn't see that. But how Abel's identity can be used to demonstrate such thing??

Comment: @user619894 I did it, thank you very much for the suggestion